# Using Default constraint during BULK INSERT where data conversion error occurs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to use BULK INSERT to insert 3rd party reports. One of the columns has call duration using TIME data type, however if for some reason they don't have a call time they have the report label it as N/A which results in errors during the BULK INSERT:
`Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 9, column 11 (call_duration).`

The column in question `call_duration` has a default constraint of '00:00:00' I would like the system to use if/when there is an error flagged during the BULK INSERT in that column (or any column for that matter with a default constraint)

UPDATE: Here's my BULK INSERT statement:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.TempYellowPages
FROM 'Z:\YP.txt'
WITH (
FIRSTROW=2,
FIELDTERMINATOR='\t',
ROWTERMINATOR='\n',
MAXERRORS = 99
)
```

I'm looking to use the default constraint of the columns within the `TempYellowPages` table when there's an issue with the data. I can't use CONVERT (to my knowledge) as the data isn't in a source table, it's coming directly from a file. Here's an example of some of the fields the file could have:

```
Date    Time    Caller Name Caller Number   Call Duration
9/2/2015    4:03:18 PM  John Smith  (555) 444-1115  0:04:38
9/2/2015    10:53:09 AM Thomas Bush (555) 444-1115  N/A
9/2/2015    10:26:28 AM Burt Fenimore   (555) 444-1115  0:05:53
```

Comment: do you have access to the sql server client?

Comment: yes, I have access

Comment: hi , how is the input file generated? like is it coming from a *nix  machine, hadoop cluster , export from an xls(x)?...

Answer (score 0):

convert the "call_duration" column to varchar in the source query, use CONVERT function. Be aware how SQL Server understand '00:00:00' (maybe as 1900-01-01') and change the report condition to show 'N/A' according to the '1900..' value